# How to delete a row from mysql via php

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, delete-row

Brushing up on php and working on a simple program where I've run into an issue. I can't seem to figure out how to delete a mysql row. I will link my script in a pastie document so you can see how I have it set up.

I'm not familiar with AJAX or Javascript.. so I just made the delete button a form. I'd like to keep it like this for now if I can make it work.

[PASTIE HERE](http://pastie.org/4471078)

Comment: please post the specific code you're having problems with

Comment: The script is only 45 lines of code. You want me to paste the whole thing here instead of my pastie link?

Comment: your pastie link is just fine

Comment: You asked how to delete a row from mysql. You could include just the one or two relevant lines, then the question because useful for everyone, even if pastie isn't available.

Comment: Make sure you are cleaning your post data for SQL injection! Or use binding with PDO.

Comment: Thank you, I sure will. Trying to see if I can get it funcional first then will add security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 30 you have two inputs named `del`, and the second one does not contain the name to delete

```
echo '<form id="del" method="post"><input type="submit" name="del" value="X" /><input type="hidden" name="del" /></form>';
```

Need to change to something like -

```
echo '<form id="del" method="post"><input type="submit" name="del_submit" value="X" /><input type="hidden" name="del" value="'.$del.'" /></form>';
```

Then change lines 12-13 to

```
if (isset($_POST['del_submit'])) {
mysql_query("DELETE FROM name WHERE name='".$_POST['del']."'");
```

Please note that `mysql_` functions are depreciated, and you are subject to sql injection.

Comment: Sean, this worked simply and perfectly. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Sean, could you provide me with a link on switching my mysql functions to PDO or something more secure? I wasn't aware they were depreciated.

Comment: You can look at [http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: Sean, here is my revised code. I've converted it to mysqli. Could you tell me if this is more secure, and other ways to improve it? I'd really appreciate it! http://pastie.org/4471333

Comment: Yes, it is more secure. Noticed that when you changed to mysqli you removed `$_POST['del']` from line 13, so now `$del` in `$con->query("DELETE FROM name WHERE name='$del'");` is not set. Make sure to add `$del = $_POST['del']` before line 13. Also make sure this page is only accessible to those who you want to be able to delete names.

Comment: Well I should of been clearer. I guess other ways you could advise to improve security.. would it be necessary to use "mysql_real_escape_string" since I'm using mysqli now? Those types of things. And the script works perfectly as it is now.. should I add `$del = $_POST['del']` back in even though it's working perfectly?

Comment: If it is working, no need to add it back in. I am also learning `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*`, so I cannot provide the best help on security/sanitizing. Here are 2 links to look at - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327974/when-to-sanitize-php-mysql-code-before-being-stored-in-the-database-or-when-it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327974/when-to-sanitize-php-mysql-code-before-being-stored-in-the-database-or-when-it)

Answer (score 2):

change:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM name WHERE name=.'$del'.");
```

to:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM name WHERE name='".$_POST['$del']."'");
```

becuase:
1. you should get rid of the . inside the query, dot is used for string concatenation.
2. you want to use the value of `$_POST['$del']` - the parameter `$del` is not set

**Updates:**

1. change `<input type="hidden" name="del" />`  to: `<input type="hidden" name="del" value="theNameYouWantToDelete"/>`
2. you give the same name to all the form elements (name="del") - this is not recommended! better set a different name to each object.
3. please do not use `mysql_*` - it's deprecated and vulnerable to sql-injection, use PDO or MySQLi instead.

Comment: He would also need to pass relevant data with `$_POST['del']`. Which he isn't.

Comment: @Brandon - please try again :)

Comment: No parse error this time. But the row still exists in the table unfortunately.

Comment: That's because `$_POST['del']` has no data... like I said.

Comment: @Brandon - please echo the value of `$_POST['del']` before the query runs

Comment: @brandon On line number 41 in given link you are creating the hidden field with no value.

Comment: @Brandon I just updated my answer with Rupesh's comment, he's right - you're submitting the page with null value in `$_POST['del']`

Answer (score 0):

You're not properly concatenating the `$del` variable. You could simply use:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM name WHERE name='$del'");
```

Also, you need to set `$del` before the `DELETE` query. That variable hasn't been declared before you tried to use it, so it will be `null`.

Comment: Blake, could you instruct me how to get this working then? I declared $del in the while loop but I guess I can't access it outside of that loop.